# qt - How to override dragMoveEvent in QGraphicsScene with the same functionality

Tags: qt

I derived a class from QGraphicsScene. Then I overrided the dragMoveEvent. But now I cant move any items in my QGraphicsScene. Somebody please help me to create the dragging movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC you can call directly call the overridden method by QGraphicsScene::dragMoveEvent from your own function.